# Freeze keyboard and mouse on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-services

I want to create a program for a computer lab. The computers in lab are running Windows 7 and are connected via LAN. The program should freeze keyboard and mouse when PC gets disconnected from LAN and also show a fullscreen message.

Currently I have created the first version of this program that works almost fine. It runs with startup. But the problem is that the users can kill it from Task Manager. I've tried running it as a windows service and it runs but cannot interact with desktop, so it cannot freeze the keyboard and mouse.

Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved it.
The reason my program could not interact with desktop is that it runs in Session 0.
This is because the Windows services run in session 0 and cannot directly interact with desktop. Here by interaction I mean receiving keyboard, mouse events and creating or accessing windows in user's desktop.

So I created a service that runs with SYSTEM account. It will create the "freezer process" in user's session. Also this process will run with SYSTEM account, so the normal user will not have privileges to kill.